# Como faço para fazer duas referencias de uma tabela em outas 2 tabelas?

Tags: sql, codeigniter, lógica, mysql

Bem, tenho 3 tabelas

1. tbl_usuarios
2. tbl_artigo
3. tbl_perfil

Preciso que a tbl_usuarios tenha relação com a tbl_artigos e com a tbl_perfil.
 Como poderia ser feito?

Tabela tbl_usuarios:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| usuario_id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| usuario_usuario | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| usuario_email   | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| usuario_senha   | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| usuario_imagem  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| usuario_status  | int(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| id_perfil       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Tabela tbl_artigo

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| artigo_id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| artigo_titulo | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| artigo_imagem | varchar(80)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| artigo_autor  | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| artigo_post   | text         | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| artigo_data   | timestamp    | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| artigo_status | int(1)       | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| id_artigo     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Tabela tbl_perfil:

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| perfil_id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| perfil_cargo     | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| perfil_telefone  | int(30)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| perfil_descricao | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id_perfil        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Isso servira para que quando o usuário escrever o seu artigo eu pegarei a imagem do usuário que esta na tbl_usuario e outras informações que estão em outra tabela

Preciso saber como faço isso.

Comment: Você pode usar o $this->db->join("a", "cod=cod1");

Comment: Vou montar a query pra te mostrar!

Comment: Qual é a diferença entre a tabela "tbl_perfil" e a tabela "tbl_usuarios" ? Os campos do perfil não podem ficar na tabela usuários? Ficaria melhor de sse jeito. Depois era só usar uma chave estrangeira no campo artigo_autor que faz referência ao usuario_id.

Comment: Entendi, parasse ser uma boa ideia.